# Is CSV file upload of data , through db migration in Ruby on Rails is a good practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using factory-girl, faker gems to upload test data to my demo applications. I got to see a fellow worker who did Sample CSV test data migration onto tables. Is this a good practice?

Pranava

Comment: The advantage of the CSV is that it contains actual data to test against. Whereas you can manipulate Faker to fit in with your framework

Comment: Okay i see what you meant..Thanks for help.